# Disable selectability for a space

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```css
.meta {
  user-select: none; 
}

.meta + .bash::first-letter {
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<span class="meta">$</span>
<span class="bash"> ls</span>
```

Now I want the user to be able to select the `ls`, but not the `$` (including the space).

While this works for the `$` character, it does not work for the space after it. Why not? what's wrong with my selector?

PS: I have no influence on the HTML code, my *only* option is to make changes to the CSS.

Comment: created jsfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/nzewm0jv/

Comment: ::first-letter selector is used to add a style to the first letter of the specified selector and can only be used with block-level elements. Span is not a block-level elements.

Comment: @JalayOza What's the point of creating a fiddle? There's a working snippet in the question itself.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Fiddle contains proposed working solution

Comment: @sasha_gud No, the fiddle just contains OP's code.

Comment: @ajreal Is there a workaround for this, without breaking the layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, created on @ajreal's comment.

```css
.meta {
  user-select: none;
}
.bash{
  display: inline-block;
}
.meta:after {
  content: '\00a0';
}
```

```html
<span class="meta">$</span><span class="bash"> ls</span>
```

Comment: You changed the HTML. OP says they have no access to the HTML.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Updated my answer, check once.

Answer (score 3):

First, the `::first-letter` selector works only for block container boxes (won't work for inline elements).

Second, it seems it can't select a space. If you set the spans to `inline-blocks`, still the first letter that gets colored red is "l" and not a space.

```css
.meta, .bash {
  display: inline-block;
}

.meta {
  user-select: none; 
}

.meta + .bash::first-letter {
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<span class="meta">$</span>
<span class="bash"> ls</span>
```