# Disable selectability for a space in <code> tag

Tags: html, css

Building on [Disable selectability for a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451735/disable-selectability-for-a-space) I now have an even more special problem. Basically, I have the following code:

```css
.meta {
  user-select: none;
}

.bash {
  display: inline-block;
}

.meta:after {
  content: '\00a0';
}
```

```html
<pre><code><span class="meta">$</span><span class="bash"> ls</span></code></pre>
```

Now, I want the user to be able to select the `ls`, but not the `$` (including the space). While this already works for the `$` character, it does not work for the space after it. How can this be solved?

And, due to the `<pre>` tag there are now two spaces: While the one inserted by CSS can not be selected, the other one still can. One way to solve this is to add a `text-indent: -7px` and a `overflow-x: hidden` to the `.bash` class, but this breaks the layout (for whatever reason).

So, how can this be fixed without touching the HTML? (Please note that I have *no* influence on the HTML code, only on the CSS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pre` tag preserves spaces and line breaks, you need to set `.bash`'s white-space to initial, but IE does not take initial value so it's better to use both `white-space: normal;` and `white-space: initial;`

```css
.meta {
  user-select: none;
}

.bash {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  white-space: initial;
}

.meta:after {
  content: '\00a0';
}
```

```html
<pre><code><span class="meta">$</span><span class="bash"> ls</span></code></pre>
```